# 144 hz Monitor used with Two Other 60 hz's?

Tags: multiple-monitors, refresh-rate

I'm building a new PC and want to get three monitors. I only use one screen for gaming/videos, so figured I could just get one 144 hz monitor for that purpose. In order to save a bit of money, I'm thinking about keeping the other two at 60 hz.

Will I run into any issues having two different refresh rates? Will my 144 hz downscale to 60 hz? Can I run all three from the same video card or should I get two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One card should be perfectly fine and no the other 2 monitors will not lower your refresh rate on your third monitor.

Edit: Wording.